# Change Chrome Dev Tools Touch Cursor

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, touch, mouse-cursor

Im currently developing a web app which is mostly in dark colors. The app is operated via touch, so i set my chrome dev tools to emulate a mobile device. The problem is now that the cursor is dark on dark and i find it hard to find the cursor. Is there a way to somehow change the appearance of the mobile cursor?
I'm on windows 10 and have the latest chrome version 107.0.5304.88

I searched the installation files of chrome to somehow find the icon/picture which is used for the cursor but i don't know much about desktop apps so i didn't find anything

Answer (score 1):

1. Add device type

[image]

2. Mobile (no touch)

[image]

Comment: unfortunately the app does not work when the pointer is anything other than touch. I don't now exactly why but its somewhere in our SDK. Otherwise this would have worked